# erreur cache with external parameters

Tags: database, symfony, parameters

i would like to use external parameters to config my parameters.yml.
so i follow this tutorial :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html

in my parameters.yml i have put this :

```
parameters:
database_host: localhost
database_port: null
database_name: '%database.name%'
database_user: '%database.user%'
database_password: '%database.pass%'
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: localhost
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

it works when i run my website with this parameters except when i clear the cache with command line.
i got this error :

```
 [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
  You have requested a non-existent parameter "database.name". Did you mean this: "database_name"?
```

Do you know the solution to resolve this problem.
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

First create a php file and the logica, then import the php file to the config.yml and after comment the variables in parameters file. Have you tried to do something like this?

```
# parameters.php
$container->setParameter('database_name', $databaseName);

# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.php }

# app/config/parameters.yml
#database_name: '%database.name%'
#database_user: '%database.user%'
```

Comment: yes I just tried and it not work either.I feel it is that these external parameters are not accessible from the php CLI mod

Comment: I modified my answer # parameters.php $container->setParameter('database_name', $databaseName); you can call now this variable '%database_name%', it worked for me, @strauss

Comment: yes, it works but if you clean cache by command, you will see that the parameters do not exist.it's very strange

Comment: if found the solution!!we must put a default value when exporting variables such as 'export SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER=defaultuser'